# simple callback control using boost::asio and c++11 lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda, boost-asio

I'm implementing simple server with `boost::asio` and thinking of io-service-per-cpu model(each io_service has one thread).

What i want to do is, let an io_service to request some jobs to another io_service( something like message passing ).

I think `boost::asio::io_service::post` can help me.

There are two `io_service`s, `ios1`,`ios2`,

and a job(function) `bool func(arg *)`,

and a completion handler `void callback(bool)`.

So I want `ios1` to request a job, `ios2` runs it and notify `ios1` to finish and finally `ios2` runs the handler.

```
ios2.post( 
 [&ios1, arg_ptr, callback, func]
 {
    bool result = func(arg_ptr);
    ios1.post( []{ callback(result) } );
 } );
```

Is this code works? and is there any smarter and simpler way?

**EDIT:**

I found that the second lamda inside the `ios1.post()` can't reach the function pointer `callback`. It's out of the scope... so I'm trying another way using `boost::bind()`.

```
ios2.post(
 [&ios1, arg_ptr, callback, func]
 {
    ios1.post(  boost::bind( callback, func(arg_ptr) )  );
 } );
```

I removed one stack variable bool and it seems better.

But using c++11 lambda and `boost::bind` together doesn't look so cool.

How can i do this without `boost::bind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found that the second lamda inside the ios1.post() can't reach the function pointer callback. It's out of the scope

I don't think that's the problem.

You're trying to capture `callback` but that's not a function pointer, it's a function.  You don't need to capture a function, you can just call it!  The same applies to `func`, don't capture it just call it.  Finally, your inner lambda refers to `result` without capturing it.

It will work if you fix these problems:

```
ios2.post(
        [&ios1, arg_ptr]
        {
            bool result = func(arg_ptr);
            ios1.post( [result]{ callback(result); } );
        }
    );
```

You're second version is not quite the same, because `func(arg_ptr)` will get run in the thread of `ios1` not `ios2`, and I'm not sure either version fits your description:

> So I want `ios1` to request a job, `ios2` runs it and notify `ios1` to finish and finally `ios2` runs the handler.

In both your code samples `ios1` runs the `callback` handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
typedef int arg;
int main()
{
    arg * arg_ptr;
    boost::function<void(bool)> callback;
    boost::function<bool(arg *)> func;
    boost::asio::io_service ios1, ios2;
    ios2.post( 
     [&ios1, arg_ptr, callback, func]
     {
            bool result = func(arg_ptr);
            auto callback1 = callback;
            ios1.post( [=]{ callback1(result); } );
     } );
}
```